# Having some trouble identifying GPIO pins

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3b+

Okay, some quick background first, I just managed to install Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 3B+, and I started to try to do some projects. I started off with just writing python, which I'm happy to say that I have a very basic understanding of now. After a few hours of programming, I had decided to try and start off with a physical project. I bought a Freenove pi ultimate starter kit and got straight to work. I connected my breadboard with some wires, LED, resistors, the good stuff, but at the last minute, I had trouble decided which GPIO pins were which. I looked up a picture online, but I didn't know if my Raspberry Pi was facing the wrong way, or which was was in or out. I know this is a really basic question, but I don't want to risk breaking my Pi for something stupid like this. Is there an easy way of knowing what GPIO pin is which?

Update: Thank you so much! I've started making some circuits and all of your answers have helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go through **https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/** you will get all  help documents including schematics. Best way is type "pinout" in command prompt you will get pin configuration according to version of your raspberrypi.

Comment: Another answer already mentioned the `pinout` command.

Answer (score 5):

I always use the pinout website - its interactive and the best I have come across:

https://pinout.xyz

The image represents the circuit board and the edge between the mounting holes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run `pinout` at a command line and you'll see a pinout for your Raspberry Pi model. https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli_tools.html

Comment: Unfortunately `pinout` tells me my Pi3B+ and Pi3A+ have "Wi-fi : False
Bluetooth : False" despite the fact I am accessing them over WiFi and the Pi3A+ has "USB ports : 4". And doesn't appear to know which model. Doesn't actually inspire confidence.

Comment: There hasn't been an update since the recent 3+ models, that's all. But the GPIO pins haven't changed since the Pi 1 B+.